# ¿Por qué no se agrega el api key al header?

Tags: java, api

Tengo el siguente código:

```
        String plataforma = "pc";
        String nombreUsuario = "makuka_10";
        String urlApi = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/"+plataforma+"/"+nombreUsuario;


        URL url = new URL(urlApi);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("trn-api-key", "api-key"); // no puse el api key original 
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Sin embargo el servidor me retorna 403 forbidden y cuando veo los headers el header trn-api-key no está.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentacion la llave debe ser `TRN-Api-Key`

```
con.setRequestProperty("TRN-Api-Key", "API KEY");
```

En este caso es importante definas la llave como se indica ya que es "case-sensitive"

`plataforma` debe ser "CONSOLE".

Comment: muchas gracias amigo ! , de todos modos probe y sigue devolviendo estado 403 forbidden.
Sigue sin pasarse la api key no se que es lo que pasa.
Muchas gracias por responder i

Comment: Plataforma debe ser "CONSOLE".

Answer (score 0):

La api Key debe estar activa, es decir, debes dejar un numero de tarjeta de crédito valido para activar la api Key y que esta funcione de manera adecuada. Tienes que ir a la consola de Google, y en la parte de facturación agregar la tarjeta de crédito. No te va a cobrar sino un dólar y luego de esto, podrás usar la api Key sin restricciones.